# XUnit Fails Randomly

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit

I have a function app and a lot of asynchronous functions. Also, I have an XUnit project for my tests but It fails randomly when I run it locally or via VSTests.

My test project dependencies are:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExpectedObjects" Version="2.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Neleus.LambdaCompare" Version="1.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My function app's dot-net version is .Net 6.0

I tried to use **xunit.runner.json** to prevent parallel run, different collections and some other suggestions but it is still the same.

Comment: That usually indicates your test cases are not really independent of each other. You will have to share more details with readers (like the entire code base), or there is no real answer.

Comment: Are they failing or not running? Is there any indication in the log that an unhandled exception occured? I had a situation that a memory error in some of the tests was bringing the whole test process down and some random tests simply didn't run.

Comment: All test cases run. But some of them fail randomly. If I try to run one by one, all of them are successful. I couldn't debug because of that. Thanks.